# PHP Send Email if "to" more than 1 email on my case

Tags: php, email

How to automatically send email using PHP if:

1. Only 1 email
2. More than 1 email

in PHP variable.

```
$body = "test";
$qDept = oci_parse($c1, "
            SELECT
            D.DEPARTMENTID,
            D.DEPARTMENTNAME,
            E.EMAIL_SCHEDULERID_FK,
            E.DEPARTMENTID_FK,
            E.EMAIL_ADDRESS
            FROM
            WA_GA_TBL_DEPARTMENTS D,
            WA_GA_TBL_EMAILLISTS E
            WHERE
            D.DEPARTMENTID = E.DEPARTMENTID_FK AND
            D.LOCATIONID_FK = 'LC0001'
        ");
        oci_execute($qDept);
        while($dDept = oci_fetch_array($qDept))
        {
            $to = $dDept['EMAIL_ADDRESS'];
            $body .= "test test";
        }

$host = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $port = '587';
        $username = 'donotreply@test.com';
        $password = 'aw00w?';

        $headers = array(
         'Port'          => $port,
         'From'          => $from,
         'To'            => $to,
         'Subject'       => $subject,
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        );

        $recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;

        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
         array ('host' => $host,
         'auth' => true,
         'username' => $username,
         'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
           echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
           echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }
        }
```

You can see on variable `$to`

If same Department and more than 1 email so I want it to be like : someone@test.com, someone1@test.com

But if only 1 email then someone@test.com.

The issue right now, if email more than 1 email it only send to the first email.

I think is it need using array? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: You can use an `if/else` condition while counting rows that are more than one.

Comment: Concatenate the addresses using`$to .= ` OR put email sending code inside the loop and send one wmail to each recient

Comment: @all, give me an example would be better :)

Comment: $to = $dDept['EMAIL_ADDRESS'];

is it array or string type when multiple email?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam string, not an array

Answer (score 0):

you have to put

```
$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

in the while bracket,

```
while($dDept = oci_fetch_array($qDept))
    {
        $to = $dDept['EMAIL_ADDRESS'];
        $body .= "test test";
        $mail = $smtp->send(yourvar1, yourvar2, yourvar3);
    }
```

So, it will be looping as many email you have.

Comment: what is mean yourvar1, yourvar2, yourvar3?